# How to change the aggregation calculation in react-table.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to get a proper average aggregation from react-table. For the moment, when you do an average on aggregation, it does the average of the sub-rows. If you only have 1 level of aggregation, no problem. If you have several levels, it brings a problem. It does the average of the averages of the sub-rows. This is not correct.

I've tried to aggregate it differently, but I don't know where to get the values for all the sub-rows in all the aggregation.

```
const data = [
  {
    region: "South",
    country: "Spain",
    item: "item1",
    item_type: "type1",
    value: 140
  },
  {
    region: "South",
    country: "Spain",
    item: "item2",
    item_type: "type2",
    value: 240
  },
  {
    region: "South",
    country: "Spain",
    item: "item3",
    item_type: "type1",
    value: 140
  },
  {
    region: "South",
    country: "Spain",
    item: "item4",
    item_type: "type2",
    value: 240
  },
  {
    region: "South",
    country: "France",
    item: "item5",
    item_type: "type1",
    value: 140
  },
  {
    region: "South",
    country: "France",
    item: "item6",
    item_type: "type2",
    value: 240
  },
  {
    region: "North",
    country: "UK",
    item: "item7",
    item_type: "type1",
    value: 140
  },
  {
    region: "North",
    country: "UK",
    item: "item8",
    item_type: "type1",
    value: 240
  },
  {
    region: "North",
    country: "UK",
    item: "item9",
    item_type: "type1",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    region: "North",
    country: "UK",
    item: "item10",
    item_type: "type2",
    value: 30
  },
  {
    region: "North",
    country: "UK",
    item: "item11",
    item_type: "type2",
    value: 450
  }
];
```

Those are my columns:

```
const columns = [
        {
          Header: "region",
          accessor: "region"
        },
        {
          Header: "country",
          accessor: "country"
        },
        {
          Header: "item",
          accessor: "item"
        },

        {
          Header: "item_type",
          accessor: "item_type"
        },
        {
          Header: "value",
          accessor: "value"
        }
      ];
```

And this is my component:

```
<ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} pivotBy={["region", "country", "item_type"]} />
```

*In that example, Average for Spain is 145, the average for France is 505. If you do the average for all the rows, you get 265. And yet, in the table, it does the average of France and Spain, so 145 + 505 / 2. This is not correct. It should be 1590/6.*

Answer (score 1):

I ran in this problem too and haven't found a solution that included the builtin aggregation flows in react-table. Ended up doing the aggregation separatly and displaying then the aggregated data in react-table.

Comment: That's a pity. Let's hope the new version will fix that problem! I've ended up using https://react-pivottable.js.org to have a correct calculation.